# Using format specifier in for a URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, zbar-sdk

I'm having problems with using format specifiers for url's. Using the zBar scanner to scan a php link. I've spent a lot of time researching here on overflow but I cannot find the answer.

This is the code I use in my viewcontroller.m:

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.co.uk/TM.php?id=%@",self.scannedValue]]];
//NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"JSON"]];



NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:Nil];
```

I'm trying to get the part after id to take in any integer number like `200`,`201`,`202`,`203`,...

For some strange reason it only works when I type the number in itself as `id=201` or `id=202`.

when I use `NSLog` for `NSLog(@"%@",scannedValue)` it shows the following:

```
2014-02-26 21:45:27.185 MeCombine[2412:60b] http://mywebsite.co.uk/TM.php?id=201
2014-02-26 21:45:27.277 MeCombine[2412:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens please?

A few notes:

scannedValue = sym.data;

is string, `sum` is `ZBarSymbol` class object

In the `ZBarSymbol` class

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *data;
```

is the starting value.

When a value is successfully scanned it will return a `NSString *data` in the delegate method.

Comment: I see http:://mywebsite.co.uk in your first quote, but http://... in the second, try checking that?

Comment: Copy your actual code. The code and the log statement don't match up currently.

Comment: @wain apologies. I have fixed that. the two colons do not make a difference. I only changed it to two instead of one from a previous post.

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide a guess, since I don't see all of your code, but here's what I think goes on:

Your http link is malformed (`http::` instead of `http:`). The `jsonData` object will be `nil` if it can't load the URL for whatever reason.

You don't do any null checking, and this `nil` object is sent to whatever method processes your json data, which throws a `NSInvalidArgumentException` if the data object is nil.

Comment: but why does it except a integer in replacement of %@ in the URL? I tried that and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

NSData's `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` does not tolerate nil URL, which in this case happens because of the incorrect URL format, notice you have two : in the URL after http. The correct URL would be.

```
http://mywebsite.co.uk/TM.php?id=%@
```

The modern and potentially more foolproof way of building URLs would be to use NSURLComponents (iOS 7 and OS X 10.9)

```
NSURLComponents *comps = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.co.uk"];
comps.query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@", self.scannedValue];
comps.path = @"/TM.php";
NSURL *URL = comps.URL;
```

The main benefit would be the ability to isolate the base URL into a constant string and then alter the query/path from elsewhere, both making things a bit more modular and easier to maintain than a hardcoded value in code.

Comment: gave it a try but it just messes up the object I created as well. Are you able to see the edited code with JSON object? That line now gives me an error

Comment: what is the last line for? I get a message saying that it never gets used.

Comment: Incompatible pointer types sending NSURL to parameter of type NS Data.

Comment: What on Earth are you doing? My snippet just shows how to get the NSURL object you need to pass to +dataWithContentsOfURL:

My snippet was not supposed to be a drop-in replacement of your code, you should really try and understand the concept and not just cobble together pieces of random code...

Comment: I'm sorry if I hurt your feelings. So let me guess, your some high class computer science student who knows every detail about objective c. Well my expertise is in both photography and finance and I have only learnt objective C within a month. Sometimes people learn by copy and pasting a little bit of code and giving it a few tweaks to see what happens if you do it this way or that way.

Comment: I'm sure if you struggled to do something and you've spend days trying to fix something and you have little experience, you would probably do the same thing. All I'm asking for is a little help as this one thing cause the whole of my first ever application to work.

Comment: As I said, my snippet gives you an NSURL object that is to be used with the +dataWithContentsOfURL. The topic I did not cover was making blocking network requests (as that call would make), i.e you should be using a NSURLConnection to fetch data from the web or at least executing this code from a background thread (otherwise your app will be unresponsive for the duration of the request). I have no problem with people piecing together code from different sources, I do have a problem with people not trying to understand the code they are copy-pasting.